# How to use json decoded data in blade laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

part of this data in store method decoded and i want to use this encoded data in blade template:
**How is this possible?**

```
public function store(VehiclesRequest $request)
{
     $data = Vehicle::create([
        'container_type' => $request->container_type,
        'type' => $request->type,
        'delivery_capacity' => $request->delivery_capacity,
        'plate_number' => json_encode($request->plate_number),
        'chasis_number' => $request->chasis_number,
        'capacity_dimensions' => json_encode($request->capacity_dimensions),
        'fuel_consumption_rate' => $request->fuel_consumption_rate,
        'capacity_weight' => $request->capacity_weight,
        'insurance_expire_date' => json_encode($request->insurance_expire_date),
        'insurance_type' => $request->insurance_type,
        'is_available' => $request->is_available,
    ]);
    return redirect()->action('VehicleController@index');
}
```

**VehicleController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $vehicles = Vehicle::all();
    return view('vehicle.index', compact('vehicles'));
}
```

**view:**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach(vehicles as $vehicle)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $vehicles->plate_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicles->delivery_capacity }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**i used from `{{ json_decode($vehicles->plate_number) }}` in blade template but an error occurred.**

Comment: How does your json data look like and how do you want it presented?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: i used from `{{ json_decode($vehicles->plate_number) }}` in blade template but an error occurred.

Comment: provide a plate_number encoded json

Comment: ___An Error?___ What error, that would make a useful addition to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Decode json data in view.blade.php like this :

```
<tbody>
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    <tr>
        <td>
            @foreach(json_decode($vehicles->plate_number) as $plate)
                {{ $plate['variable_name'] }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>{{ $vehicles->delivery_capacity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```